# How to get APNs token of iOS in Flutter for push notifications?

Tags: flutter

How to get APNs number for IOS device in flutter for push notification?
FirebaseMessaging provides a device token. It's work for Android, but for IOS I need APNs token for push notification. Please give me suggestions.

Comment: Please try this, hope it will resolve your issue,
http://myhexaville.com/2018/04/09/flutter-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/

Comment: @FenilPatel Thanks for giving me a suggestion. But I need to send APNs token in the backend for notification in iOS device. FCM token is working fine for Android.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 5):

You can get APNs Token from `FirebaseMessaging` ...

just check the platform if it's iOS/macOS then put this condition

```
var iosToken=await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken();
```

in the case of android/Web its gonna return null

Comment: What's funny is that it is not mentioned in any guide I read recently. I feel like this is very important notice - "If you use FCM as a notification delivery service, use this method to get token for ios device. If your server communicates with the Apple directly - use This method"

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin [flutter_apns](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_apns), it is based on the FirebaseMessaging, but for IOS, you can get token from APNs and do not depend on FCM.